# Before Start React Native what are the basic language known

Tags: react-native

I have experience in iOS native develop. I am new to react native.  before to start what are language i must be familiar?. like Java Script

Comment: React-native uses Javascript. Frankly, this can easily be found if you Googled about it.

Comment: Yes.. I know that..but some of said you should Familiar with HTML,CSS,JS,ES6,Node JS and React. I want clearly ?

Comment: I answered but I also downvoted. This is just a google search away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clearly depends on what exactly do you want to do.

Only React Native? Then it is just a mix of JavaScript and Node.JS. You don't specifically use HTML, but CSS helps because it uses the same concept and classes.

Do you want to also have a custom package? You will need some basic knowledge in Android/Java and iOS.

Do you want to add Unit Testing / Automation? Jest, which is basically JavaScript and Appium for example. The latter supports varios languages but you might want to tart with Python because you can run that in Cloud services for automation.

Then, are you going to build the backend too? NodeJS, Java, Net, PHP, Python, etc, etc, etc.